# How to add a menu in [ctrl] popup menu of a method?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I don't know how to describe is exactly......

Er, you know, when you press [ctrl] and move your mouse over a method name, there is a popup menu like this:

```
==========
Open Declaration
Open Implementation
Open Return Type
========
```

Now I want to add my own actions here, but I didn't find where to write these code even I grep "Open Return Type" in JDT source.

Anyone has an idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those things where you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and hover your mouse over are generally called "hyperlinks", in your specific example "Java element hyperlinks".

If you want to provide your own hyperlinks, you have to implement a [hyperlink detector](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_workbench_texteditor_hyperlinkDetectors.html) and register it using the extension point `org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.hyperlinkDetectors` from the plug-in `org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor`. The example below is the hyperlink detector that creates the "Open Return Type" entry you mentioned in your question.

```
<extension
  point="org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.hyperlinkDetectors">
  <hyperlinkDetector
   class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaElementHyperlinkReturnTypeDetector"
   id="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaElementHyperlinkReturnTypeDetector"
   name="%JavaElementHyperlinkReturnTypeDetector"
   targetId="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaCode">
  </hyperlinkDetector>
</extension>
```

If you want to extend this specific case you have to use the same `targetId` and provide your own implementation of `IHyperlinkDetector`. You can take a look at [JavaElementHyperlinkDetector](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.3/org.eclipse.jdt/ui/3.9.0/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/javaeditor/JavaElementHyperlinkDetector.java#JavaElementHyperlinkDetector) for an example implementation of `IHyperlinkDetector`.